# Ember.js Bindings and Templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm testing the main features of Ember.js. According to the provided Guide, the following code, using simply Bindings and Auto-Updating templates should output `Hey there! This is My Ember.js Test Application!` but instead it outputs `Hey there! This is !`.

JS:

```
// Create the application.
var Application = Ember.Application.create();

// Define the application constants.
Application.Constants = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: 'My Ember.js Test Application'
});

// Create the application controller.
Application.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();

// Create the application view.
Application.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application',
    nameBinding: 'Application.Constants.name'
});

// Create the router.
Application.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/'
        })
    })
})

// Initialize the application.
Application.initialize();
```

HBS:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Hey there! This is <b>{{name}}</b>!</h1>
</script>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are referring to a view's property from the template, you must prepend it with the `view` keyword.

So try

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <h1>Hey there! This is <b>{{view.name}}</b>!</h1>
</script>
```

it should work.

Oh, I forget something, the binding is wrong, you have to refer to an object not a class. Try

```
Application.constants = Ember.Object.create({
  name: 'My Ember.js Test Application'
});
```

and

```
Application.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application',
  nameBinding: 'Application.constants.name'
});
```

Comment: Nope, I still see the same thing. And this is without any modifications, I'm using the starter kit as served by the Ember.js website.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out my mistake was using `Ember.Object.extend` instead of `Ember.Object.create`. One more thing, why does the Ember.js guide omit the `view.` prefix when it comes to handlebars vars?

Comment: It's some mistakes for now, but are going to be corrected to the next release of docs: see my pr here, https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/206 and in general the doc-refactor branch